Joining with condition in Pandas like in SQL ON clause
I want to write the below type of query in Python. But basic python filtering acts like I did use WHERE clause in SQL, not ON for filtering. Could anyone please help? Appreciate for your support.
select * 
from t1 
left join t2 on  t1.key = t2.key 
             and t2.x2 <= t1.x 
             and t2.y2 > t1.y

I tried the below Python code, and it is not working same with SQL query.
df = t1.merge(t2, how = 'left', on = 'key')
df = df[df[x2] <= df[x]]
df = df[df[y2] > df[y]]


Merge the dataframes, then check which locs does not match the condition, then set those locs as NaN.
While converting to NaN the datatype becomes float, so you might need to convert them to integer.
t1_data = {'key': [1, 2, 3, 4],
           'x': [5, 6, 7, 8],
           'y': [10, 11, 12, 13]}
t2_data = {'key': [2, 3, 4],
           'x2': [6, 7, 8],
           'y2': [16, 17, 18]}

t1 = pd.DataFrame(t1_data)
t2 = pd.DataFrame(t2_data)

merged = pd.merge(t1, t2, on='key', how='left')
condition = (merged['x2'] <= merged['x']) & (merged['y2'] > merged['y'])

# This identifies the rows which does not satisfy the condition, and then set x2 and y2 to NaN 
merged.loc[~condition & merged['y2'].notna(), ['x2', 'y2']] = pd.NA

Pandas Output
   key  x   y   x2    y2
0    1  5  10  NaN   NaN
1    2  6  11  6.0  16.0
2    3  7  12  7.0  17.0
3    4  8  13  8.0  18.0

The output with SQL matches with the Pandas output.
Fiddle
SQL Output
key x   y   x2      y2
1   5   10  null    null
2   6   11  6       16
3   7   12  7       17
4   8   13  8       18


In the first row y2 i.e 8 is smaller than x i.e 10, I have also updated the answer with SQL comparison

Ah! I see the issue now, Thank you so much @JonSG, I have edited the answer and took an indirect way this time :)

Nicely done. I believe this does produce the result the OP is after.

Thanks to you for identifying the error in the first place :)
uumm I did edit the Fiddle and then 'ran' it and refreshed the page, but it still is referring to the previous one, unsure why tho

created a new Fiddle and edited the link, should be fine now,Thank you!

If you want to join dataframes as you would tables via a complex join that is beyond what pandas.merge() supports, one cheeky way forward might be to use an in-memory sqlite database and your original query.
import pandas
import sqlite3

t1 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'key': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'x'  : [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'y'  : [10, 11, 12, 13]
})

t2 = pandas.DataFrame({
    'key': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'x2'  : [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'y2'  : [8, 16, 17, 18, 19]
})

query = """
select * 
from t1 
left join t2 on  t1.key = t2.key 
             and t2.x2 <= t1.x 
             and t2.y2 > t1.y
"""

with sqlite3.connect(':memory:') as conn:
    t1.to_sql('t1', conn, index=False)
    t2.to_sql('t2', conn, index=False)
    result = pandas.read_sql_query(query, conn, dtype="Int32")

print(result)

Note dtype="Int32" to give you a nullable value.
That will give you:
   key  x   y   key    x2    y2
0    1  5  10  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1    2  6  11     2     6    16
2    3  7  12     3     7    17
3    4  8  13     4     8    18

